# Yii - How To Show Other Property Not Its ID

Tags: php, yii

I have related tables on database like picture below:
[image]

Then, I have page to view my file like picture below:
[image]

I want to show its username, not it's ID.
Here is my code in view/file/_view.php

```
<div class="view">

    <b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id_file')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->id_file),array('view','id'=>$data->id_file)); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('nama_file')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->nama_file); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('deskripsi')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->deskripsi); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id_user')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id_user); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('id_kategori')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id_kategori); ?>
<br />

<b><?php echo CHtml::encode($data->getAttributeLabel('tgl_post')); ?>:</b>
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->tgl_post); ?>
<br />

<hr />
</div>
```

FileController.php

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}
```

index.php that output _view.php

```
<?php
    $this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Files',
    );
 ?>

<h1>Files</h1>

<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
)); ?>
```

Can you help me to change it? Thanks a lot.
P.S.: sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to have a relation to the user table in your model, I assume you have since you have FKs on the pic above. Lets assume the relation is "user" and in the user table the field you want to display is "username".

You should replace:
`php
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->id_user); ?>`

with:
`php
<?php echo CHtml::encode($data->user->username); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Logically i would say: Just use $data->username, but since you didn't add the Controller function that renders this view it's impossible to know if that is a part of your data. You might want to add that function to clear up things.

From your code I'm getting the impression that you are not using models, otherwise you would just have a "user" instance passed to the view on which you could fetch any of the properties, including the $user->username.

Based on this code it seems as if you are doing a lot of effort to work around the entire framework. Just my $0.02 :)

Comment: I am sorry I really a newbie in Yii, but I used model, it is generated automatically with Gii. So, I have to add a function in my controller? Do you have an example what function I have to add?

Comment: Okay, Gii generated models is a start. What the controller function concerns: You shouldn't have to add it, it should be the one that is rendering that view. It would be handy to have that source too

Comment: so, I have to modify function actionView? I have updated my post above, I post my actionView in the FileController.php

Comment: Seems we are still missing some information, I assume you have a view.php file as well that is using a CListView or something alike to output the _view.php? As you are giving the view an "$oModel" and end up using $data everywhere

Comment: yes I have index.php to output _view.php, I update my post. So what's next?

Comment: With the code you posted, this cannot work: The controller includes view.php and passes it a variable "$model" which is the model you loaded there. But then in your actual view you seem to magically conjure a $dataProvider out of nowhere. I was trying to be sure that my anser is correct but you're making it very hard by not really trying to figure out things yourself along the way. Where does the $dataProvider come from?

Comment: thanks too for your advices Blizz I have solved it, helped by Nikola